# android studio: release apk is not signed

Tags: android-studio, release

*** I have rephrased the post since originally posted ***

When I try to run a just-built release apk, I get an error "the apk for your currently selected variant ... is not signed."  This is in the Edit Configuration popup.  Here are my steps:

1. In the Build Variants tab, select "release"
2. In the menu, choose Build -> Generate Signed APK
3. In the popup, fill in the fields for the key store and passwords.
4. In the second panel, change the destination folder to ...\app\build\outputs\apk (see note * below)
5. Observe notification in upper right of studio: APK(s) generated successfully.
6. In the menu, click Run -> Run App.
7. I get an "Edit configuration" popup with the error "The apk for your currently selected variant ... is not signed.

So, why this error?  The APK generated appears to be valid.  I have successfully posted it to the Android Store (alpha testing only) and verified that stack dumps are obfuscated.

What I can't do is download it (step 6 above) to my device.  I guess that's ok since I can download the debug version just fine.

(*) Android Studio defaults the output for the release apk to a higher, presumably more convenient directory.  However I find it harder to manage the consistency of generated files when they are scattered about so I prefer all the generated apks in one place.

Comment: "I built the release version with the key store specified and passwords supplied.": How did you build it? With android studio UI or gradle command? Need more info.

Comment: just-built; sorry, misspelt

Comment: I used the studio - the Build -> Generate Signed APK... wizard.

Comment: @PeriHartman can you post your answer

Comment: I don't have an answer.  Maybe it works in A.S. 2.0 - I haven't upgraded yet.

Answer (score 42):

**Go to File\Project Structure**

[image: Signing Tab]

[image: Flavor Tab]

[image: Build Type]

Done! ;)

Comment: Thanks. If there are other modules, enough to sign only `app`.

Comment: Legend Spotted . Awosome answer.

Comment: This interface isn't up to date with the current version of AS. Can someone update it?

Comment: As of Android Studio Arctic Fox:
File -> Project Structure -> Build Variants -> Signing Config

Answer (score 24):

Set signing config in project structure.

1. File -> Project Structure...
2. Select Modules/app (or other module)
3. Click Signing tab and fill in.
   Key Alias and **Key Password** comes first.
   Not same order in "Generate Signed APK" dialog.
4. Click Build Types tab and select release.
   Select "config" in Signing config dropdown list.
5. Click OK to close Project Structure.
6. Run -> Run app

---

Run (or Debug) app seems to use apks built with "Buiild -> Build APK".
So, we should set signing config if build variants of app module is "release".

Comment: You may jump to Signing tab by pressing "Fix" button on the right side of the  text of error

Answer (score 14):

Add this line to your release {...} inside build.gradle

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.config
```

Comment: Saved me alot of time. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

**First**, Create a keystore file if there isn't one.

1. Click **Build** from the dropdown menu
2. Select **Generate Signed APK**
3. Click **Next**
4. Click **Create New Keystore**
5. Fill out the form for **keystore path, alias, password** for keystore and alias, at least one field in the certificate area.
6. Click **OK**
7. A keystore file will be created in the specified keystore path.

**Second** update the **app build gradle file** to someting like this one to include the signing config.

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'mykeyalias'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('/Users/yourname/path/to/the/android/project/folder/android_project_folder_name/app/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}
```

**Third**, build and run the app, done.

Answer (score 3):

In https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#secure-shared-keystore it is written that you shouldn't keep credentials information in `build.gradle` and VCS. So create a signing config file (Build > Generate Signed APK...), then do so.

> Create a file named `keystore.properties` in the root directory of your
>   project. This file should contain your signing information, as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> storePassword=myStorePassword
> keyPassword=mykeyPassword
> keyAlias=myKeyAlias
> storeFile=myStoreFileLocation
> ```
>
> In your module's build.gradle file, add code to load your
>   `keystore.properties` file before the `android {}` block.
>
> ```
> // Create a variable called keystorePropertiesFile, and initialize it to your
> // keystore.properties file, in the rootProject folder.
> def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
>
> // Initialize a new Properties() object called keystoreProperties.
> def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
>
> // Load your keystore.properties file into the keystoreProperties object.
> keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
>
> android {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> You can refer to properties stored in `keystoreProperties` using the
>   syntax `keystoreProperties['propertyName']`. Modify the `signingConfigs`
>   block of your module's `build.gradle` file to reference the signing
>   information stored in `keystoreProperties` using this syntax.
>
> ```
> android {
>     signingConfigs {
>         config {
>             keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
>             keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
>             storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
>             storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
>         }
>     }
>     ...
> }
> ```

Optionally in `build.gradle` you can add:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

Now you may make a signed apk. Don't forget to exclude `keystore.properties` from VCS.

Answer (score 2):

Try add this in your build file:

```
buildTypes {
release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the  "signingConfig signingConfigs.release"

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in the build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue turned out I misconfigured the `signingConfigs` property.

Specifically, I thought I didn't have a password for the key where I actually had set it. After adding the missing information, it worked.

```gradle
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/xxx/xxx/keystore/xxx.jks')
            storePassword '123'
            keyPassword '123' // this was missing
        }
    }
```